# Find value in <li> from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling Ajax via function. When the ajax has been completed, it unable to find value in `<li>`

A Function that use ajax:

```
function findList(postCode) {
        $.getJSON("/list/" + postCode,
            function(data) {
                if (data.length > 1)
                {
                    $.each (data, function (index, element) {
                        if (element != "address") {
                            $('#order-list-form').append($("<li></li>").attr("value",data[index].value).text(data[index].name));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

If a page loaded, find a value from `$("#PostCode").val()` and then execute `findList()`, once it has been completed, it need to find a value DUS123 in `<li>` which has been populated via ajax and then add class `selected-address` - This don't seem to work.

```
if ($("#PostCode").val() != "") {

   // Execute Ajax
   findList( $("#PostCode").val() )

   // Not working here
   // When Ajax completed, I want to find find the value in <li> and add class selected-address
   $("#order-list-form li").find('value="DUS123").addClass("selected-address");
}
```

Comment: you have a parse error. `'value="DUS123"`  has a missign closing quote. It's need to be: `'value="DUS123"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector in the call to `find` is not valid.  To search attributes, you need to wrap them with `[]`:

```
$("#order-list-form li").find('[value="DUS123"]').addClass("selected-address");
```

However, since you're also setting the attribute directly on the `li` element itself, you need to find the attribute on that element, not on a child element which the above selector will be doing:

```
$('#order-list-form li[value="DUS123"]').addClass("selected-address");
```

Another issue is that due to the way requests are sent and processed by ajax, this line of code will run *before* the ajax request has completed, and so before the element has even been appended to the document.  To fix this you have two options.  The quick and dirty way, which is to make the ajax request synchronous, for which I'll leave you to research the [`getJson`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) and [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) methods to find out how to do.

The second, and more correct way, is to either run this line of code within your success function in your call to `getJson`:

```
function findList(postCode) {
    $.getJSON("/list/" + postCode,
        function(data) {
            if (data.length > 1)
            {
                $.each (data, function (index, element) {
                    if (element != "address") {
                        $('#order-list-form').append($("<li></li>").attr("value",data[index].value).text(data[index].name));

                    }
                });
            }
            $('#order-list-form li[value="DUS123"]').addClass("selected-address");
        });
}
```

Or you can allow your `findList` function to take a callback, and use that:

```
function findList(postCode, callback) {
    $.getJSON("/list/" + postCode,
        function(data) {
            if (data.length > 1)
            {
                $.each (data, function (index, element) {
                    if (element != "address") {
                        $('#order-list-form').append($("<li></li>").attr("value",data[index].value).text(data[index].name));

                    }
                });
            }
            callback();
        });
}

if ($("#PostCode").val() != "") {
    findList( $("#PostCode").val(), function() {
        $('#order-list-form li[value="DUS123"]').addClass("selected-address");
    });
}
```

Comment: As @MaxBumaye has pointed out, this code is also running at the wrong time - you'll need to combine these answers for a final fix.

Comment: What about ajax to wait to complete?

Comment: You _could_ make the ajax synchronous, but that will lock up the UI thread in the browser while the request takes place, and defeat the object of it being ajax in the first place.

Comment: What I can do to allow ajax runs async and what changes I need to do? You could update answer

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I've updated the answer with your options

Answer (score 0):

you are running this:

```
$("#order-list-form li").find('value="DUS123").addClass("selected-address");
```

before:

```
 $.getJSON("/list/" + postCode,
            function(data) {
                if (data.length > 1)
                {
                    $.each (data, function (index, element) {
                        if (element != "address") {
                            $('#order-list-form').append($("<li></li>").attr("value",data[index].value).text(data[index].name));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

because the ajax runs async and is waiting for a callback....

solution woulkd be to put

```
$("#order-list-form li").find('value="DUS123").addClass("selected-address");
```

inside your callback

Comment: Could you update your answer to fix ajax waiting for a callback?